# facebook-php-sdk:I can't update the infomation of the Adset

Tags: php

```
$adset->update();
```

It's only to update the status of the Adset, Changing of the others param, It's failing!

what's the reason?
Who can help me solve?

Grateful！

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $adset->update(
        array(
            \FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => 1100,
            \FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields::TARGETING=>(new \FacebookAds\Object\Targeting())->setData(array(
                \FacebookAds\Object\Fields\TargetingFields::INTERESTS=>array(
                    'id'=> 6009003307783,
                    'name'=>'Accounting and finance',
                )
            ))
        )
    );
```